# How can I use Pandas to add a count with a certain interval to the entire csv file?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a conditional csv file and I want to add an interval count for example from 1 to 6 to get something like this:

| A header | Another header | Another header |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 1 |
| С | 7 | 2 |
| V | 4 | 3 |
| A | 1 | 4 |
| Q | 1 | 5 |
| V | 2 | 6 |
| N | 8 | 1 |
| A | 2 | 2 |
| L | 4 | 3 |
| A | 6 | 4 |
| S | 4 | 5 |
| F | 3 | 6 |

Is it possible to implement this using Pandas ?

Comment: your question is not descriptive enough. please add reproducible code snippet and input and output required accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use vectorial code for efficiency, `numpy` is the perfect tool:

```
import numpy as np

N = 6
df['Another header'] = np.arange(len(df))%N+1
```

output:

```
   A header   Another header   Another header
0         A                 2               1
1         С                 7               2
2         V                 4               3
3         A                 1               4
4         Q                 1               5
5         V                 2               6
6         N                 8               1
7         A                 2               2
8         L                 4               3
9         A                 6               4
10        S                 4               5
11        F                 3               6
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct this should be solution:

```
import pandas as pd
# create 'a header column'
df = pd.DataFrame({"a header":["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n"]})
# create 'another header column'
df["another header"] = [(number % 6) +1 for number in range(0,len(df["a header"]))]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work.

```
from itertools import cycle
c = cycle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
df['Another header'] = [next(c) for count in range(df.shape[0])]
```